# How to get data in Realm (swift 2) with key

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7, realm

I can't understand how to find all data in line, if I have key. 
When I want to add, I generate unique String:

```
    try! uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in
            let findOut = TaskList()
            let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
            findOut.id = uuid
            findOut.name = "New name"
            findOut.taskMin = 0
            findOut.taskHours = 0
            uiRealm.add(findOut)
            })
```

When I want to change data, it's something like this:

```
try! uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in
let findOut = TaskList()
findOut.id = "A9600D00-5E2A-47B2-A05E-4341EDFEE227"
findOut.name = "Change text"
uiRealm.add(findOut, update: true)
    self.readTasksAndUpdateUI()
})
```

But I can't understand, if I need just read data from all line? I need put it in variable.

For example: 
**I need get .name, .taskMin, .taskHours from line with .id = A9600D00-5E2A-47B2-A05E-4341EDFEE227**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use special method to retrieve object from Realm using it's primary key.

```
let id = "A9600D00-5E2A-47B2-A05E-4341EDFEE227"
let findOut = uiRealm.objectForPrimaryKey(TaskList.self, key: id)
print(findOut.name)
print(findOut.taskMin)
print(findOut.taskHours)
```

For this to work, you need to declare primary key in Model:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
}
```

Comment: I have another problem, when I add this code: "incorrect argument label in call (have 'forPrimaryKey:', expected 'value:')" 
Do you know, what I have to change?

Comment: Sorry, API has changed since I used it. I've changed answer.